# Change img class name from ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following ajax response which is generated by a server sided script:

```
<div class="parent"><img class="icon" src="../images/icons/inv_boots.PNG"/></div>
<div class="item-title3">Testname</div>
<div class="item-level">20</div>
```

At the moment I store the image tag in the variable "icon" like that;

```
let icon = $content.siblings('[class^=parent]').html()
```

Now I want to change the image class name of `<img class="icon"` to "icon22".

This is my code so far:

```
<script language="javascript">

jQuery(function($) {
  
  $('*[data-id]').each(function() {
    let $tooltip = $(this);
    let id = $tooltip.attr("data-id");

    $.ajax({ 
      url: "/datenbank/itemscript.php",
      type: "GET",
      data: {
        "var": id
      }
    }).then(function(data) {

      let $content = $(data);
      let title = $content.siblings('[class^=item-title]').text()
      let icon = $content.siblings('[class^=parent]').html()

     var item_title = $content.siblings('div[class*="item-title"]');
     console.log(item_title);
     var ClassName = '';
     var classes = item_title.attr('class').split(/(\s+)/); 
     $.each(classes , function(i , v){
     v = v.trim();  
     if(v.indexOf('item-title') > -1){  
    ClassName = v; 
    }
  }); 
      
      
  $tooltip.tooltip({
        tooltipClass: "test",
        content: data,
    position: {
      my: "left+153 top+20",
    collision: "flipfit"
    }

      });
      
       $("<div class=\"" + ClassName + "\">" + icon + "" + title + "</div>").appendTo($tooltip);
    });
  });
    
});
</script>

<a data-id="12555"></a>
```

Comment: Hi , you can try `$content.siblings('[class^=parent]').find("img").addClass("icon22").removeClass("icon")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `$data` is a jQuery object holding the response, you can use `find()` to retrieve the `img` element within it and then `toggleClass()`:

```
$content.find('img.icon').toggleClass('icon icon22');
```